# Redirect all child taxonomy to its parent

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, hierarchical, template-redirect

Is it possible to automatically redirect a `child taxonomy` to its `parent`, therefore not having a public page at all for the `child taxonomy`?

**Example:**

I have a taxonomy called `venue`, this is set up with `'hierarchical' => true,`. This allows me to add venues which have been renamed for sponsorship purposes (eg: City Theatre becomes the XZY City Theatre, then ABC City Theatre, they are all the same building/location just different names).

Therefore if you clicked on a link for a `child taxonomy` (XZY City Theatre) you'd be taken to `https://domain.com/venue/city-theatre` NOT `https://domain.com/venue/xyz-city-theatre`.

**Venue Taxonomy**

This is my code for creating the taxonomy itself

```
add_action( 'init', 'gd_tax_venues', 0 );

function gd_tax_venues() {

    $plural = 'Venues';
    $single = 'Venue';
    $slug = 'venue';

    $labels = array(

        'name' =>  $plural,
        'singular_name' =>  $single,
        'menu_name' =>  $plural,
        'all_items' => 'All' . $plural,
        'parent_item' => 'Parent ' . $single,
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent ' . $single . ':',
        'new_item_name' => 'New ' . $single,
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New ' . $single,
        'edit_item' => 'Edit ' . $single,
        'update_item' => 'Update ' . $single,
        'view_item' => 'View ' . $single,
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate ' . $plural . ' with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove ' . $single,
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular ' . $single,
        'search_items' => 'Search ' . $single,
        'not_found' => 'Not found',
        'no_terms' => 'No' . $single,
        'items_list' => $single . ' list',
        'items_list_navigation' => $single . ' list navigation',

    );

    $args = array(

        'hierarchical' => true,
  'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'meta_box_cb' => false,
  'show_admin_column' => true,
  'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'public' => true
        
    );
    register_taxonomy( $slug, array( 'gig' ), $args );

}
```

**taxonomy-venue.php**

This is the code for the taxonomy page itself.

The parent shows all the posts which are assigned to both the parent and children (This is what I want displayed for all).

```
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'venue' ); 
    $terms_ids = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
    }
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'gig',
      'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'venue',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => $terms_ids
        )
      ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul>
      <?php 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post();?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  <?php }
```

If the redirect isn't possible, how can I show the `parent` and `sibling` posts on all `child` pages? and possibly change the `canonical link` on child pages to point to the `parent` page?

**Edit: Redirect works with**

Working based on the answer from mrcodefinger. Adding the following to the top of 'taxonomy-venue.php'

```
    $term = get_queried_object();
    
$parent = ( isset( $term->parent ) ) ? get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, 'venue' ) : false;
    
    if( $parent ) {
      $url = get_term_link($term->parent);
      wp_redirect( $url, '301' );
    }
```

Comment: taxonomies don't have parent/child relationships, are you sure you didn't mean _parent terms_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your $term have parent and then redirect using [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

```
<?php
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $parent = ( isset( $term->parent ) ) ? get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, 'types' ) : false;

    if( $parent ) {
        wp_redirect($term->parent);
    } 
?>
```

I hope this helps!

Greetz

Comment: Legend, got it working based on the advice you gave to use `wp_redirect()`, updated the question with the solution as well for others - Thank you

Comment: Cool, you're welcome!